# How can I sum the product of two two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, multiplication

So I got a code with two arrays: one array contains tickets sold for three cinemas and the other one contains the adult and kid prices. My code outputs the total for every cinema separately (3 lines of output) but I need the total number of those 3. So instead of printing 828 for cinema1, 644 for cinema2, 1220 for cinema3 and I need it to print 2692 (total of 3 cinemas). How can I sum the 3 products with a for loop? Here's the code:

```
public class Arrays {
    public Arrays() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float[][] a = new float[][] {{29, 149}, {59, 43}, {147, 11}};
        float[] b = new float[] {8, 4};
        String[] s = new String[] {"cinema 1", "cinema 2", "cinema 3"};
        String[] t = new String[] {"Adults", "Children"};
        int i,j;
        System.out.println("Cinema Complex Revenue\n\n");
        for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0 ; j < 1 ; j++ )
            {
                System.out.println(s[i] + "\t$" + 
                 (a[i][j] * b[j] + a[i][j + 1] * b[j + 1]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAlU6.png)

Comment: Please be sure to format your code properly, i.e. be sure that you use proper indenting.

Comment: Also to remember to produce a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Especially the minimal part. If removing some code will clear up the entire example, then remove it. An example of this would be the print statements you have near the beginning of your code. Refer to this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MatthewCliatt got it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just code what you want.

```
int i, j;
float sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < a[i].length && j < b.length; j++) {
        sum += a[i][j] * b[j];
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Or if you want to use only one `for` loop, it may be

```
int i;
float sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < a.length * b.length; i++) {
    sum += a[i / b.length][i % b.length] * b[i % b.length];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is 1 nested for-loop:

```
Integer totalCost = 0;

for( i = 0 ; i<b.length; i++ ) {
  //you should check if the a[i].length == b.length, and throw an exception if not!
  for( j = 0 ; j<a.length; j++) {
     totalCost += b[i]*a[j][i];
  }
}
System.out.println("Total cost: "+totalCost.toString());
```